# How to avoid undefiend observables with NGRX?

Tags: angular, ngrx

In my project I try to integrate NGRX Store afterwards,
i.e. the previous application architecture has not taken this into account.

As described in the documentation, the usual way is always to fill the components with observables coming from the store "from the beginning".

Even if data arrives later, the observables already exist.

But in my application there are frequent scenarios in which data should only be called up "at the push of a button".
and only then do the corresponding observables come into play.

In the example below, I've shown a fictitious component that suggests a nickname, but only "defines" the observable when the button is pressed.
I do this so that I don't have to make any case distinctions in the template itself with regard to the existence of the observables (i.e. test whether they are undefined or not).

However, this seems to me to be thinking past the Angular idea, since I completely do without the async pipe.
Does NGRX have a definition of how to deal with such scenarios? I couldn't find anything.

```typescript
@Component({
    template: '
    <input type="text" #seedInput></input>
    <span>{{currentNicknameSuggestion}}</span>
    <button (click)="loadANewNickName(seedInput.nativeElement.value)">new suggestion please!</button>
    '
})
export class NicknameSuggestingComponent {

    newNickname$: Observable<string> | undefined;
    currentNicknameSuggestion: string = 'No idea yet...'; // placeholder which is mandatory due to customer specifications

    constructor(private store: Store<{}>) {}

    /*
    * When the user clicks "new suggestion please!"-button
    */
    loadANewNickName(_seed: string) {
        // this triggers an ngrx/effect which loads a nickname string via http
        // and then when the loadANicknameSuccess-Actions will get recieved by the reducer,
        // a new suggestion will be placed in the store
        this.store.dispatch(loadANewNickname({seed:_seed}));

        // selector for the suggestion in the store
        this.newNickname$ = this.store
        .select(selectNicknameSuggestion)
        .pipe(
            tap(name => this.currentNicknameSuggestion = name)
        );

        // because i don't want to use the async pipe in the template
        // I have to manually descripe to the observable here
        // Thats because I don't want to blow up the template with case destinctions
        // (does newNickname$ is undefined or not)
        this.newNickname$.subscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: The `async` pipe as more powerful as you think, so it is important use it from my point of view. Why defining the observable as undefined instead of the value. This is the better idea. This is something you could control very easily using a subject or a behavior subject. The observable should be setup in constructor and in your loadNewNickName method you update the behavior subject with the new value.

Comment: Whatever happens, I would not manage this mechanism in the component, I would create some kind of service that can use `BehaviorSubject` like @ThomasRenger said, and this service would make the switch between an initiial stream of data and eventually the NgRx Store, on demand. Well I never tried that for the record.

Answer (score 0):

From your description and example, I don't see any reason not to simplify this code and get rid of your "undefined" Observable altogether. There is simply no use case where you actually make use of its "undefined" status in your code.

Note that whatever is in the store - whether the user has clicked the button already or not - you *still* have some string value rendered in the template at all times (either the placeholder or the loaded value). Why not set the store to be initialized with this value from the beginning, and then simply always render whatever the store is actually returning at the moment?

```
// ngrx reducer:
export const initialState: State = {
  nicknameSuggestion: 'No idea yet...' // initial state value goes here
};
export const nicknameState = createReducer(
  initialState,
  ...
}


// component:

@Component({
    template: '
    <input type="text" #seedInput></input>
    <span>{{currentNicknameSuggestion$ | async}}</span>
    <button (click)="loadANewNickName(seedInput.nativeElement.value)">new suggestion please!</button>
    '
})
export class NicknameSuggestingComponent {

    // no additional synchronous properties storing Observable values
    newNickname$: Observable<string>; // no need for undefined 

    constructor(private store: Store<{}>) {
    // select from the store, 
    // then let async pipe always render whatever is there
        this.newNickname$ = this.store.select(selectNicknameSuggestion);}
    }

    loadANewNickName(_seed: string) {
        // loads a nickname and adds it to the store
        this.store.dispatch(loadANewNickname({seed:_seed}));
        
    }
}
```